# How to only show month and year in wordpress post

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I cant figure out how to only show the month and the year in entry-date of my wordpress posts
Any suggestions? It doesnt seem to be a standard configuration by the wordpress control panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the date format here: `Admin` > `Settings` > `General` > `Date Format`

However, your theme may not be using this setting. In that case, you have to edit your theme and use

```
<?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?>
```

in every file that displays the post/page date.

- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/591/how-to-get-the-date-format-and-time-format-settings-for-use-in-my-template

Answer (score 0):

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Usage

```
<?php date('Y-m', strtotime($your_time_variable)); ?>
```